# How can I return {vW,vH}, it actually returns Undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

I'm trying to read the metadata from an *.mp4 video using `ffprobe` and `exec`, then parsing its `json` results but it returns undefined...

```
const video_metadata = `ffprobe ".\\video.mp4" -v error -show_entries stream=width,height -of json`;

const {vW,vH} = exec(video_metadata, async (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        await console.error(`exec error: ${err}`);
        return;
    }
    const j = JSON.parse(stdout);

    return j.streams[0].width, j.streams[0].height;
});

console.log(vW); // Undefined
console.log(vH); // Undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your return line like so:

```
return { vW: j.streams[0].width, vH: j.streams[0].height }
```

Comment: you can't `await` exec, as it does not returns a promise. The values of the parsed json can only be accessed in the callback. You could wrap your exec with a promise and the you'd be able to `await` it

Comment: Despite I got it downvoted *(by someone other I guess)*, Thank you sir for the help. I figured it out and solved it wrapping it within a promise as you said.